# Compiler error when trying to import Google Maps SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps

I've now tried several times to import the Google Maps SDK in my Xcode-projekt following this guide (and trying several tips from googling): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

I keep getting compiler-errors when I insert the code in my AppDelegate.swift file. My code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyCn_wFzr8s3Z571fUmNrabsCW4GJZaXl-A"];
        return true
    }
```

The errors is around the hole GMSServices-part

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I would be so grateful for any kind of help or hints for me to get this to (finally) work. If you haven't guessed, I'm quite new at this. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using obj-c syntax. In swift it is written as

```
 GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCn_wFzr8s3Z571fUmNrabsCW4GJZaXl-A")
```

Comment: Oh my that was it! I was thinking about it, but had gotten the impression, that you could use the syntax from Obj-C in Swift? Well, nevermind - thank you! :-D